# Locating a value in XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have an xml file loaded into an XDocument that I need to extract a value from, and I'm not sure of the best way to do it. Most of the things I'm coming up with seem to be overkill or don't make good use of xml rules. I have the following snippet of xml:

```
    <entry>
      <observation classCode="OBS" moodCode="EVN">
        <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.6.2.12" />
        <code code="121070" codeSystem="1.2.840.10008.2.16.4" codeSystemName="DCM" displayName="Findings">
        </code>
        <value xsi:type="ED">
          <reference value="#121071">
          </reference>
        </value>
      </observation>
    </entry>
```

There can be any number of `<entry>` nodes, and they will all follow a similar pattern. The value under the `root` attribute on the `templateId` element contains a known UID that identifies this entry as the one I want. I need to get the reference value.

My thought is to find the correct templateID node, back out to the observation node, find `<valuexsi:type="ED">` and then get the reference value. This seems overly complex, and I am wondering if there is another way to do this?

EDIT

The xml I receive can sometimes have xml nested under the same node name. In other words, `<observation>` may be located under another node named `<observation>`.

Comment: You have to show your whole XML input, because there is a namespace `xsi` used in sample part, but we don't know how it's declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have problems, because your document uses Namespaces, and your query is missing them.

First of all, you have to find `xsi` namespace declaration somewhere in your XML (probably in the most top element).

It will look like that:

```
xmlns:xsi="http://test.namespace"
```

The, take the namespace Uri and create `XNamespace` instance according to it's value:

```
var xsi = XNamespace.Get("http://test.namespace");
```

And use that `xsi` variable within your query:

```
var query = from o in xdoc.Root.Element("entries").Elements("entry").Elements("observation")
            let tId = o.Element("templateId")
            where tId != null && (string)tId.Attribute("root") == "2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.6.2.12"
            let v = o.Element("value")
            where v != null && (string)v.Attribute(xsi + "type") != null
            let r = v.Element("reference")
            where r != null
            select (string)r.Attribute("value");

var result = query.FirstOrDefault();
```

I have tested it for following XML structure:

```
<root xmlns:xsi="http://test.namespace">
  <entries>
    <entry>
      <observation classCode="OBS" moodCode="EVN">
        <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.6.2.12" />
        <code code="121070" codeSystem="1.2.840.10008.2.16.4" codeSystemName="DCM" displayName="Findings">
        </code>
        <value xsi:type="ED">
          <reference value="#121071">
          </reference>
        </value>
      </observation>
    </entry>
  </entries>
</root>
```

The query returns `#121071` for it.

For your input XML you will probably have to change first line of query:

```
from o in xdoc.Root.Element("entries").Elements("entry").Elements("observation")
```

to match `<observation>` elements from your XML structure.

Answer (score 0):

Would something along the lines of the following help?

```
   XDocument xdoc = GetYourDocumentHere();
   var obsvlookfor =
       xdoc.Root.Descendants("observation")
           .SingleOrDefault(el => 
                el.Element("templateId")
                    .Attribute("root").Value == "root value to look for");

   if (obsvlookfor != null)
   {
       var reference = obsvlookfor
           .Element("value")
           .Element("reference").Attribute("value").Value;
   }
```

My thought is as follows:

1. Pull out all the observation elements in the document
2. Find the only one (or null) where the observation's `templateId` element has a `root` attribute you're looking for
3. If you find that observation element, pull out the `value` attribute against the `reference` element which is under the `value` element.

Comment: Thank you for the response. It looks great, and I think that, under normal circumstances, this would have done it. However, I got a null back. I believe it was because the observation node was nested under another observation node, so it found the root observation but not the nested. I should have put this in my question, but I hadn't noticed it.

Comment: I played around with the code you suggested, and found that even when I changed the value to match the outer observation node, I was still getting a null for obsvlookfor.

Comment: @Tim How are the observations nested in the XML? As this will affect how you will need to build up your query. I would recommend breaking the query down into its pieces and examining the results you get back at each stage in the debugger to help you determine the optimum query you need, nested observations could make the query somewhat trickier to manage, but not impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to include the Namespace in your LINQ.  To retrieve that you would do something like this:

```
XNamespace ns = xdoc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
```

Then in your linq:

```
var obsvlookfor = xdoc.Root.Descendants(ns + "observation")
```

I know I had some issues retrieving data once without this.  Not saying its the issue just something to keep in mind particularly if your XML file is very in depth.